# Error "at least two inputs are required; got 1." Python

Tags: python, pandas, anova

I would like to do a one-way ANOVA on this data frame (picture). When I used Python, I got this kind of error

```
TypeError: at least two inputs are required; got 1
```

I understand why but I don't really know how to solve it.

```python
import scipy.stats as stats

frame = frame.dropna()
images = set(frame["path"])
frame["key_resp.keys"] = frame['key_resp.keys'].str.replace("right","1"
for img in images:
data = frame.loc[frame["path"]==img]
fvalue, pvalue = stats.f_oneway(data['key_resp.keys'])
print(fvalue, pvalue)
```

[image]

Comment: From the docs for [`f_oneway`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.f_oneway.html#scipy-stats-f-oneway): *"The one-way ANOVA tests the null hypothesis that two or more groups have the same population mean. The test is applied to samples from two or more groups, possibly with differing sizes.  [...]  The sample measurements for each group. There must be at least two arguments."*

Comment: Yes, thank you. Do you know what function allows you to do an anova with only one dependent variable?